# Can I use Polearm master with a spear and a whip to hold opponents at 10ft away?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack

RAW + [This errata](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/1337077670283100161?lang=en) states:

> While you are wielding a glaive, halberd, pike, quarterstaff, **or spear**, other creatures provoke an opportunity attack from you when they enter your reach.

Say an opponent is standing 10’ away from me, and I am wielding a whip and a spear. If my opponent moves from 10’ to 5’, or 10’ to 15’ I can make an opportunity attack against them in either case. I cannot, however, make an  opportunity attack when an opponent moves from 15’ to 10’. Is my understanding correct?

I’ve been looking for an answer to this for a War caster Hexblade I’m making. I want to use this to hold opponents in range of the damage dealer tanks in my party without risking my much lower health pool as much.

Comment: What do you mean by "hold opponents"? Are you trying to prevent them from moving by being able to perform an AoO if they move out of that 10 foot range?

Comment: @AllanMills Yes, I am trying to keep the opponent within the 10’ range band, without letting them move within 5’ of me or move 15’ away from me.

Comment: Related: "[How does Polearm Master interact with Quarterstaff and Whip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115025)" and "[When are Opportunity Attacks provoked while holding a reach and a non-reach weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47864)"